# Fade out, pause, then fade in an element - CSS Only

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to fade out an element, keep that element faded out for, say, 5 seconds, then fade back in the element. I am trying to achieve this using only CSS and not jQuery.

Currently I have set two elements to start fading after 2 seconds, have a fade duration of 2 seconds and then reappear as soon as the duration ends.

[Here's a fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/8hwr3rb3/).

And the code:

CSS:

```
.hideMe1{
     animation:hideMe 0.5s 1;
    -webkit-animation:hideMe 2s 1; /* Duration of fading and repetitions */
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    animation-delay:2s; /* Pause before fade */
    -webkit-animation-delay:2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;  /* End by showing the content */
} 

.hideMe2{
     animation:hideMe 0.5s 1;
    -webkit-animation:hideMe 2s 1; /* Duration of fading and repetitions */
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    animation-delay:2.5s; /* Pause before fade */
    -webkit-animation-delay:3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;  /* End by showing the content */
} 

@keyframes hideMe{
    from {opacity :1;}
    to {opacity :0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes hideMe{
    from {opacity :1;}
    to {opacity :0;}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="hideMe1">
I'll fade first
</div>
<div class="hideMe2">
My turn to fade
</div>
```

How can I make each element stay faded for 5 seconds (for example), before reappearing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For achieving that effect, you would have to modify your keyframes like in the below snippet.

- Set the `animation-duration` such that it is the total time for the fade-out + pause + fade-in. Here I have set the duration as 10s (2.5s for fade-out + 5s pause + 2.5s for fade-in).
- Set the keyframe percentages to match the expected durations like below:

  - At `25%` mark (which is nothing but `2.5s` of `10s`) change the `opacity` from `1` to `0`.
  - A `5s` pause period is nothing but `50%` of `10s` and so make the element hold its state till the `75%` mark. It is critical that the `75%` keyframe is also added (even though the element stays in the state) because otherwise the element would start fading-in from the `25%` mark itself.
  - Starting at the `75%` mark, make the element's `opacity` change gradually from `0` to `1` and thereby producing the fade-in effect.

**Note:** I have removed the vendor-prefixed versions of the properties to keep the demo simple and I've also removed the repetitive declaration of `animation-fill-mode` and `-webkit-animation-fill-mode` as at any point of time only one would be used by a browser. Webkit browsers would use the prefixed one as it appears last whereas other browsers would use the unprefixed one (and thus would result in cross-browser differences).

```css
.hideMe1 {
  animation: hideMe 10s 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.hideMe2 {
  animation: hideMe 10s 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
@keyframes hideMe {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hideMe1">
  I'll fade first
</div>
<div class="hideMe2">
  My turn to fade
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect. FYI this is being used in an email, hence the vendor specific versions, as some platforms pick and choose a version they like the look of meaning I have to declare the same thing several times!

Comment: @Olly: That's fine mate. I omitted them only to keep it simple. One recommendation that I would do with vendor prefixes is to always include the standard (un-prefixed) version at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to manually use the keyframes to time the animation. Take a look at this:

```css
.hideMe1 {
  animation: hideMe 5s 1;
  -webkit-animation: hideMe 5s 1;
  /* Duration of fading and repetitions */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  /* Pause before fade */
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  /* End by showing the content */
}
.hideMe2 {
  animation: hideMe 5s 1;
  -webkit-animation: hideMe 5s 1;
  /* Duration of fading and repetitions */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
  /* Pause before fade */
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  /* End by showing the content */
}
@keyframes hideMe {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hideMe1">
  I'll fade first
</div>
<div class="hideMe2">
  My turn to fade
</div>
```

```
@keyframes hideMe{
    0% {opacity :1;}
    10% {opacity :0;}
  90% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1}
}
```

Then set your animation speed to something like 7s.

Comment: @Harry Seems like it, hehe. Your answer was way better than mine anyway.