# Is there a better way to do complex animations with start and end animations that are randomized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

In this question there is an accepted answer [How to create an animation with rarity of it to appear together with animations that always appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58456789/how-to-create-an-animation-with-rarity-of-it-to-appear-together-with-animations/58467164#58467164)

It contains this

https://jsfiddle.net/d25kx6cj/5/

```
<div id="boxes">
  <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box4" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box3" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

But it looks that it's too complicated. Is there another way.

The thing is that it can become more complicated.

I'm trying to achieve this in an easier way:

```js
var box1 = document.getElementById("box1"); /* The one with the rarity */

var box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
var box3 = document.getElementById("box3"); /* Maybe give it a chance of which color */

var boxes = document.getElementById("boxes");

var box3Colors = {"blue": 90, "red": 50};

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", toggleAnimation);

boxes.classList.add("deactivated");

function randomizerWithChances(input) {
    var array = [];
    for(var item in input) {
        if ( input.hasOwnProperty(item) ) {
            for( var i=0; i<input[item]; i++ ) {
                array.push(item);
            }
        }
    }
    /*console.log(array)
    var randomizerValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
    console.log(randomizerValue)*/
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

function propertyFromStylesheet(selector, attribute) {
    var value;

    [].some.call(document.styleSheets, function (sheet) {
        return [].some.call(sheet.rules, function (rule) {
            if (selector === rule.selectorText) {
                return [].some.call(rule.style, function (style) {
                    if (attribute === style) {
                        value = rule.style.getPropertyValue(attribute);
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                });
            }

            return false;
        });
    });

    return value;
}

var box1_defaultDurs = propertyFromStylesheet("#box1", "animation-duration");
var box2_defaultDur = parseFloat(propertyFromStylesheet("#box2", "animation-duration"));
var box4_defaultDur = parseFloat(propertyFromStylesheet("#box4", "animation-duration"));
var box3_defaultDurs = propertyFromStylesheet("#box3", "animation-duration");

var box1AppearChance = {no:6, yes:4} /* 40% Appear chance I guess*/
var box4AppearChance = {no:8, yes:2}

/*
defaultDurs.split(",").map(function(item) {
  return item.trim();
});*/

var box1_defaultDur = box1_defaultDurs.split(",").map(function(item) {
  return item.trim();
});
var box3_defaultDur = box3_defaultDurs.split(",").map(function(item) {
  return item.trim();
});


var box1_defaultDurStart = parseFloat(box1_defaultDur[0]);
var box1_defaultDurEnd = parseFloat(box1_defaultDur[1]);

var box3_defaultDurStart = parseFloat(box3_defaultDur[0]);
var box3_defaultDurEnd = parseFloat(box3_defaultDur[1]);

var box3_delays = [];


function animationHandler() {
  box3.style.backgroundColor = randomizerWithChances(box3Colors);
  
  var box1Value = randomizerWithChances(box1AppearChance);
  var box4Value = randomizerWithChances(box4AppearChance);
  /*console.log(box1Value)*/
  
  box3_delays[0] = "0s"; /* Put first delay value */
  
  if (box1Value == "yes") {
   box1.classList.add("active");
    
    box2.style.animationDelay = box1_defaultDurStart + "s";
    box3_delays[0] = box1_defaultDurStart + "s";
 }
 
 if (box1Value == "yes" || box4Value == "yes") {
   box3_delays[0] = parseFloat(box3_delays[0]) + box2_defaultDur + "s";
  }
  
    /*box3.style.animationDelay = box3_defaultDurs.split(",").map(function(item) {
     var itemTrimmed = item.trim();

     return parseFloat(itemTrimmed) + box1_defaultDurStart + box2_defaultDur + "s";
    });
  }*/
  /* Use this incase you have to summarize something with two delays, if it has 0s you might want to do something else or check if it's the first one in the array just to leave it alone. But in this case I didn't needed it */
  
 
 /* box4.style.animationDelay = "0s"; To prevent NaN 
 Don't do this it it just breaks it just check it
 */
  
  if (box4Value == "yes") {
   box4.classList.add("active");
    
    if ( isNaN(parseFloat(box2.style.animationDelay)) ) {
     box4.style.animationDelay = box2_defaultDur + "s";
    }
    else if ( !isNaN(parseFloat(box2.style.animationDelay)) ) {
      box4.style.animationDelay = parseFloat(box2.style.animationDelay) + box2_defaultDur + "s";
    } /* box4 doesn't have a delay and we set one */
    
   box3_delays[0] = parseFloat(box3_delays[0]) + box4_defaultDur + "s";
    /* Delay of box3 is getting extended because of box4 when it appears */
 }


  if (box1Value == "yes" || box4Value == "yes") {
   box3.style.animationDelay = [ parseFloat(box3_delays[0]) + "s", parseFloat(box3_delays[0]) + parseFloat(box3_defaultDurStart) + "s" ];
  }
  
 if (box1Value == "yes") {
   if (box4Value == "no") {
      box1.style.animationDelay = ["0s", box2_defaultDur + box3_defaultDurStart + box1_defaultDurStart + box3_defaultDurEnd + "s"]
    }
    else {
     box1.style.animationDelay = ["0s", box2_defaultDur + box3_defaultDurStart + parseFloat(box4.style.animationDelay) + box1_defaultDurStart + box3_defaultDurEnd + "s"];
    }
    /* The + 2 is because of the box1_defaultDurStart which is needed */
    /* And box3_defaultDurEnd also needed in this case */
 }
}

function animationHandlerReset() { 
 box1.classList.remove("active");
  box4.classList.remove("active"); /* And don't forget to remove the class at the end*/
  
  /* Reset to default to stylesheet */
  box1.style.removeProperty("animation-delay");
  box2.style.removeProperty("animation-delay");
  box3.removeAttribute("style"); /* or you could do this if you didn't give it any inline style by default */
  box4.style.removeProperty("animation-delay");
} 


function toggleAnimation() {
 if (!boxes.classList.contains("deactivated")) {
   animationHandlerReset();
  boxes.classList.add("deactivated");
    btn.innerHTML = "Start Animation";
  }
  else if (boxes.classList.contains("deactivated")) {
   animationHandler();
   boxes.classList.remove("deactivated");
    btn.innerHTML = "Stop Animation"
  }
}
```

```css
#boxes {
  
}

.active {
  display: inline-block!important;
}

.deactivated {
  display: none!important;
  /*visibility: hidden!important;*/
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#box1 {background: #00afe8;}
#box2 {background: green;}
#box3 {background: blue;}
#box4 {background: orange;}

@keyframes box1-up {
  0% { top: 70px;}
  100% {top: 0px;}
}

@keyframes box1-down {
  0% { top: 0px;}
  100% {top: 70px; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes box4-anim {
  0% { height: 50px; width: 50px; transform: scale(0.5) rotate(0deg); }
  100% { height: 50px; width: 50px; transform: scale(1) rotate(180deg); }
}

@keyframes blend {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}


#box1 {
  top: 70px;
  display: none;
  animation: box1-up 2s, box1-down 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


#box2 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: blend 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*animation-delay: 3s;*/
}

#box3 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: blend 3s, blend 4s reverse;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 3s, 6s; /* Both delays start together. Probably you want the other delay to be the twice as the size of the first one in this case for the end, but maybe not everytime */
}

#box4 {
  display: none;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  animation: box4-anim 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
  <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box4" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box3" class="box"></div>
</div>


<button id="btn" style="margin-top: 200px;">Start Animation</button>
```

A simplified version of this?

Basically it is animations but it has a random chance that one of them appears. So box1 has a random chance that it appears and box4 which is the orange one, just has been called like that. Has a random chance to appear.
And box1 and box3 have a start and end animation. And that has all to be calculated and then used and I was wondering if there is an easier way to do it, because that's just so much and not sure.

I think jQuery but I don't know any good example to this.

Comment: Please describe specifically what you want to achieve, independently of other questions

Comment: @ReSedano box1 is always random with start & end animation, that's true. The start and end is not randomized separately though, but if the easy method can support it it would be good.

box2 is always present that's true

box4 I didn't made this, it was just named like that. You can just rename it to box3 but have to rename everything else to box2

box3 is always present too, that's true. The end animations start when all the visible boxes are present on the stage, that's true. However animation-delay starts as soon as any of the box are visible that means delay has to be adjusted.

Comment: Here was the first example I got sent https://jsfiddle.net/8z9obyLh/ if it helps https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0L3b.png

Comment: @ReSedano What's ment with dynamically, as in let JavaScript append or create these boxes? Probably not, but maybe an example of both would be good? For like advantages and disadvantages. The important thing is that, if dynamically created then it should not break anything in the styles.

Answer (score 2):

I post you my solution trying to make whole animation very very easy to create and to understand.

As I said in my comments, my idea came from a question: "*Ok, if some boxes sometimes there aren't, why should I always put them all on the stage? I put on stage only if I have to move it*"

So, for my solution all the boxes are create on fly with jquery, looping a javascript object that I call "*boxes*":

```
var boxes={
    "box1":{
        percentual:         40,             // 40% to appear on stage
        animation:          "box-up-down",  // animation name
        backgroundColor:    "green"         // background color
    },
    "box2":{
        percentual:         100, 
        animation:          "fade-in",
        backgroundColor:    "orange"
    },
    "box3":{
        percentual:         100,
        animation:          "fade-in",
        backgroundColor:    "blue"
    },
    "box4":{
        percentual:         20,
        animation:          "fade-in-out",
        backgroundColor:    "pink"
    },
    "box5":{
        percentual:         100,
        animation:          "rotate-in-out",
        backgroundColor:    "red"
    }
}
```

In this object you can put how many box you want (in my example they are 5). The first value is the probability of appearance on the stage (40% the first, 100% the second...). The second one define the name of animations that I wrote in CSS:

```
/*ANIMATIONS*/

.fade-in {
    animation: fade-in 1s ease forwards;
}

.fade-in-out {
    animation: fade-in-out 7s ease forwards;
}

.box-up-down {
    animation: box-up-down 7s ease forwards;
}

.rotate-in-out {
    animation: rotate-in-out 7s ease forwards;
}


@keyframes fade-in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fade-in-out {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    14% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    86% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes box-up-down {
    0% {
        top: 70px; 
        opacity: 0;
    }
    14% {
        top: 0; 
        opacity: 1;
    }
    86% {
        top: 0; 
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        top: 70px; 
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes rotate-in-out {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.5) rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    14% {
        transform: scale(1) rotate(180deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    86% {
        transform: scale(1) rotate(180deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(0.5) rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

It is important to understand that the pause is set in the animation itself. In my example I used 7seconds of animation: 1 for appear, 5 of pause period and 1 for disappear. See this for more information about the technique: [Fade out, pause, then fade in an element - CSS Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870085/fade-out-pause-then-fade-in-an-element-css-only). You have to use a proportion to find the exact percentual (in my example it was 14% and 86%).

Last arg is only the background color of the box.

To calculate the probability of appearance on the stage, I used a simple comparison between a random number and my percentage set in the javascript object:

```
let random=Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1; //random number from 1 to 100

if(value.percentual>=random){
 //create my box
}
```

This is all the script in action:

```js
var boxes = {
    "box1": {
        percentual: 40, // 40% to appear on stage
        animation: "box-up-down", // animation name
        backgroundColor: "green" // background color
    },
    "box2": {
        percentual: 100,
        animation: "fade-in",
        backgroundColor: "orange"
    },
    "box3": {
        percentual: 100,
        animation: "fade-in",
        backgroundColor: "blue"
    },
    "box4": {
        percentual: 20,
        animation: "fade-in-out",
        backgroundColor: "pink"
    },
    "box5": {
        percentual: 100,
        animation: "rotate-in-out",
        backgroundColor: "red"
    }
}


$("#btn").on("click", function(e) {

    // set the init situation if I double click during the animations
    let i = 0;
    $("#boxes").html("");


    // Create every block
    $.each(boxes, function(index, value) {

        let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1; //random number from 1 to 100

        if (value.percentual >= random) {

            let myBox = `<div id="${index}"
        class="box ${value.animation}"
        style="background-color:${value.backgroundColor};
            animation-delay:${i}s;"
        ></div>`;

            $(myBox).appendTo("#boxes");

            i++;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.box {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   transition: all 1s;
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   opacity:0;
   background-color:#f2f2f2;
   margin-right: 20px;
 }

 /*ANIMATIONS*/

 .fade-in {
  animation: fade-in 1s ease forwards;
 }

 .fade-in-out {
  animation: fade-in-out 7s ease forwards;
 }

 .box-up-down {
  animation: box-up-down 7s ease forwards;
 }

 .rotate-in-out {
  animation: rotate-in-out 7s ease forwards;
 }


 @keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
      opacity: 0;
     }
     100% {
      opacity: 1;
     }
 }

 @keyframes fade-in-out {
     0% {
      opacity: 0;
     }
     14% {
      opacity: 1;
     }
     86% {
         opacity: 1;
     }
     100% {
         opacity: 0;
     }
 }

 @keyframes box-up-down {
    0% {
      top: 70px; 
      opacity: 0;
     }
     14% {
      top: 0; 
      opacity: 1;
     }
     86% {
         top: 0; 
         opacity: 1;
     }
     100% {
         top: 70px; 
         opacity: 0;
     }
 }

 @keyframes rotate-in-out {
  0% {
      transform: scale(0.5) rotate(0deg);
      opacity: 0;
     }
     14% {
      transform: scale(1) rotate(180deg);
      opacity: 1;
     }
     86% {
         transform: scale(1) rotate(180deg);
         opacity: 1;
     }
     100% {
         transform: scale(0.5) rotate(0deg);
      opacity: 0;
     }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="boxes"></div>

<button id="btn" style="margin-top: 200px;">Start Animation</button>
```

Comment: I forgot so I know $(" ") is a short for document.getElementById but I don't know for the others or $.each also 100) + 1 because of one number missing while it does Math.random?

Comment: what's about randomized boxes that are inbetween other boxes that are not randomized?

Comment: what's with the $ or $.each is that already jQuery or that thing? ${i}

Comment: Yes, $ sign defines jQuery (`$.each()`, `$("#boxes")`...). `${i}` is a variable in a template literals =>https://css-tricks.com/template-literals/

Comment: It kinda complicated but there is still one question open. How do you handle randomized boxes that are inbetween boxes that always appear? The end animation should basically play after the other animations are done, like the example on the beginning.

Comment: So lets say I a box inbetween the other boxes, but that box does its start animation and then its end animation and then the other animation continue, what would I need to do?

Comment: I guess so, yes.

Comment: But in your example, when **box1** is present, the animation of **box2** don't wait the **box1** end animation before appear. So it is very difficult for me understand exactly what you want. It is better for you wait other answer. Perhaps other users understand your needs better than me. :-)

Comment: I'm just wondering, if it is easy when I have an animation inbetween the static (the ones that always appear but there is a randomized one inbetween those that always randomly appear). I wondering how the delay and stuff is handeld for those so that start and end animation can be played and then be continued to the next one.